# 'this' variable inside a function that sits inside another function?

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
    outer: function() {
        console.log(this);
        }
    }
```

Above code outputs *Object()* inside the console, as the this keyword points to the object 'obj'. Which means the 'this' variable points to the object in which it is present.

However,

```
function outer() {
    function inner() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

Above code outputs *window* in the console. Why does it not show the function *outer()* in the console, as according to my knowledge, a function is also an object, which can have its own properties. So if i did `this.name = "myName";` inside the inner function, i should be able to output - `console.log(outer.name)`, but that is not the case. Is there any misunderstanding on my side or does JS work like that only ?

Comment: `inner` function is not a property of `outer` function it is just in its scope

Comment: Because you're calling it like `inner()` and not `outer.inner()`. If you assigned `outer.inner = function(){...}` and called `outer.inner()`, then `this` would point to `outer`.